# How to modify a value in array of object's based on other object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

i have an object as :

```
let sample = {cat: 10 , dog: 50 , snake: 25};
```

I have the array of object as :

```
let petarray = [
    {name: 'newcat' , quantity: 20},
    {name: 'oldcat' , quantity: 15},
    {name: 'razordog' , quantity: 10}
];
```

May I know how can I modify the `petarray` quantity such that if `petarray[allindexes].name` includes any of `sample` , then `quantity = quantity * (respective number of sample )`

for eg: `petarray[0].name` includes `cat` , the quantity should be modified as `20*(10)`

any help on how to achieve is much appreciated  ,TIA (hope it is clear)

- please let me know for any more info or on what i can do to improve about this result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this,

```js
let sample = {cat: 10 , dog: 50 , snake: 25};
let petarray = [{name: 'newcat' , quantity: 20},{name: 'oldcat' , quantity: 15},{name: 'razordog' , quantity: 10}];
let sampleArrayKeys = Object.keys(sample)
petarray = petarray.map((p) =>{
 const key = sampleArrayKeys.find(sak => p.name.includes(sak))
 if (key) {
  p.quantity *= sample[key]
 }
 return p
})

console.log(petarray)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution mate , i have a weird situation where `sample = {cat: 10 , dog: 50 , snake: 25 , venomsnake : 15}` and the `name:"africavenomsnake"` , may i know how this to be matched only with `venomsnake` not `snake`

Comment: Difficult to define this case, but you can give a shot by considering value of  substring of key with max length. In venomsnake and snake example, you can see ```africavenomsnake``` has ```venomsnake``` with more length than ```snake```.

Comment: yeah mate , good point :) ....may i know how can i check this

Answer (score 2):

It can be done like this -:

```
let sample = {cat: 10 , dog: 50 , snake: 25};

const sampleKeys = Object.keys(sample);

petarray = petarray.map(item =>
    sampleKeys.find(key => item.name.includes(key))
    ? { ...item, quantity: item.quantity * sample[match] }
    : item;
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution mate :) , i have a weird situation where sample = {cat: 10 , dog: 50 , snake: 25 , venomsnake : 15} and the name:"africavenomsnake" , may i know how this to be matched only with venomsnake not snake

Comment: It will match with the first occurence in the key array, If we need it to match with  `venomsnake` we can ensure the object is like this where `venomsnake` comes first `{cat: 10 , dog: 50 , venomsnake: ##, snake: 25};` and not like this `{cat: 10 , dog: 50 , snake: 25, venomsnake: ##};`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion , i would try this way :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
let sample = {cat: 10 , dog: 50 , snake: 25};
let petarray = [{name: 'newcat' , quantity: 20},{name: 'oldcat' , quantity: 15},{name: 'razordog' , quantity: 10}];

petarray.forEach(pet => {    
    for (let sampleKey in sample) {
        if (sample.hasOwnProperty(sampleKey)) {
            if (pet.name.includes(sampleKey)) {
                pet.quantity *= sample[sampleKey];
            }
        }
    }
}, petarray)

console.log(petarray)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create mapping and then just `map` this array:

```js
let sample = {cat: 10 , dog: 50 , snake: 25};

let petarray = [
    {name: 'newcat' , quantity: 20},
    {name: 'oldcat' , quantity: 15},
    {name: 'razordog' , quantity: 10}
];

const keys = Object.keys(sample);
const mapping = petarray.reduce((a, {name})=>{
    a[name] = a[name] || {};
    let sampleKey = keys.find(k => name.includes(k));
    if (sampleKey)
        a[name] = sampleKey;
    return a;
}, {})


petarray = petarray.map(({name, quantity}) => ({ name,
    quantity: ((sample[mapping[name]] ? (quantity * sample[mapping[name]]) : quantity))}));

console.log(petarray);
```